# Vertical Tabs pull page up when active

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tabs

I used bootstrap to make some vertical tabs for my website.

I wanted some text bellow the tab title to appear only when the tab is active.

I did it, the only problem is, when I change from, for example, the tab 1 to the tab 3 the page content is pulled up.

Is there a way I can achieve this without pulling the page up?

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/hm7n5bv4/

```css
 .filler {
                background: cyan;
                height: 600px;
    }

    .nav-pills .nav-link .tab_subtitle_hide {
                font-size: 16px !important;
                visibility: hidden;
                height: 0;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    }           
    .nav-pills .nav-link.active .tab_subtitle_hide {
                color: #fff;
                visibility: visible;
                height: auto;
                opacity: 1;
                transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="filler">Hello world</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-for-teams-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-for-teams"
            role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-for-teams" aria-selected="false"><i
                class="tab_i fad fa-users-class"></i>
            <div class="tab_content">For Teams
            </div>
            <div class="tab_subtitle_hide">Similar to a hierarchical organization, Dummy text allows you to
                structure
                users.</div>
        </a>

        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-for-small-business-tab" data-toggle="pill"
            href="#v-pills-for-small-business" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-for-small-business"
            aria-selected="false"><i class="tab_i fad fa-store"></i>
            <div class="tab_content">For small business

            </div>
            <div class="tab_subtitle_hide">Similar to a hierarchical organization, Dummy text allows you to
                structure
                users.</div>
        </a>

        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-for-enterprise-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-for-enterprise"
            role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-for-enterprise" aria-selected="true">
            <div class="tab_content"><i class="tab_i fad fa-building"></i><span class="multi-company">For
                    enterprise</span><br></div>
            <div class="tab_subtitle_hide">Similar to a hierarchical organization, Dummy text allows you to
                structure
                users.</div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane active show" id="v-pills-for-teams" role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="v-pills-for-teams-tab">
            <!--Inicio sub-tab1-->..0
            <!--Fim sub-tab1-->
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="v-pills-for-small-business" role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="v-pills-for-small-business-tab">
            <!--Inicio sub-tab2-->..1
            <!--Fim sub-tab2-->
        </div>


        <div class="tab-pane" id="v-pills-for-enterprise" role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="v-pills-for-enterprise-tab">
            <!--Inicio sub-tab3-->..2
            <!--Fim sub-tab3-->
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't get what you meant by "pulling the page up". All I saw was there is a horizontal scroll bar just because you didn't have a container ('.container-fluid') wrapped with rows. https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/Ljw07ue1/3/

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply, I'll try to explain as better as I can.
To experience what im talking, scroll to the end of the page with the first tab then select the last tab, and after that, you can varely select the last tab again
https://prnt.sc/uvr6ee
https://prnt.sc/uvr7mj
https://prnt.sc/uvr6un

Comment: Hmmm you can't use the scroll bar to scroll down?

Comment: hmm, I can, just wondering if there were a way to avoid that, for example, if the user clicks multiples times on each tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the max-height of the Wrapper of the content in this case the .nav-link

Here's the example - https://jsfiddle.net/fLbuaxm8/

```
body{
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
.nav-link.active{
   max-height:500px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
.nav-link{
  max-height:0px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
.filler {
  background: cyan;
  height: 600px;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link .tab_subtitle_hide {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-pills .nav-link.active .tab_subtitle_hide {
  color: #fff;
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 600px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="filler">Hello world</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-for-teams-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-for-teams" role="tab"
            aria-controls="v-pills-for-teams" aria-selected="false"><i class="tab_i fad fa-users-class"></i>
            <div class="tab_content">For Teams
                <!--<br><div class="tab_subtitle_hide">Similar to a hierarchical organization, Dummy text allows you to structure users.</div>-->
            </div>
            <div class="tab_subtitle_hide">Similar to a hierarchical organization, Dummy text allows you to structure
                users.</div>
        </a>

        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-for-small-business-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-for-small-business"
            role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-for-small-business" aria-selected="false"><i
                class="tab_i fad fa-store"></i>
            <div class="tab_content">For small business
                <!--<br><div class="tab_subtitle_hide">Similar to a hierarchical organization, Dummy text allows you to structure users.</div>-->
            </div>
            <div class="tab_subtitle_hide">Similar to a hierarchical organization, Dummy text allows you to structure
                users.</div>
        </a>

        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-for-enterprise-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-for-enterprise"
            role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-for-enterprise" aria-selected="true" style="
    /* padding: 0 !important; */
">
            <div class="tab_content"><i class="tab_i fad fa-building"></i><span class="multi-company">For enterprise</span><br></div>
            <div class="tab_subtitle_hide">Similar to a hierarchical organization, Dummy text allows you to structure
                users.</div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane active show" id="v-pills-for-teams" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-for-teams-tab">
            <!--Inicio sub-tab1-->..0
            <!--Fim sub-tab1-->
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="v-pills-for-small-business" role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="v-pills-for-small-business-tab">
            <!--Inicio sub-tab2-->..1
            <!--Fim sub-tab2-->
        </div>


        <div class="tab-pane" id="v-pills-for-enterprise" role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="v-pills-for-enterprise-tab">
            <!--Inicio sub-tab3-->..2
            <!--Fim sub-tab3-->
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```